# Finding multiple ellipse for a non parametric Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ellipse

[image]

As shown in the image I need to find multiple ellipse (red, manually made), in the data shown by black.

Comment: Read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.3465&rep=rep1&type=pdf), a very usefull article. [Here](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~mosya/cl/) you can find code examples.

Comment: Try this also: http://basic-eng.blogspot.in/2006/01/hough-transform-for-circle-detection_23.html. I tried with this. I am able to detect 1 ellipse. but I don't know how to modify the code to detect all 3.

Answer (score 1):

It is Computer Vision problem, I suggest you to use openCV and play a bit with the image. Canny will find you the edges. Or you can fill the whole image with som watershed algorithm so there will be different regions, the small one could be the ellipse.